# I need to use "Math.floor(Math.random()" to randomly select a style from my css page.

Tags: css, random

I am in a Basic HTML/Javascript class and I cannot figure out how to   "modify the following JavaScript so that it picks one of the style classes at random each time it is called." The below code works, but it isn't randomized. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you, in advance!

```
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<link href="capstone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script>
var index = 0;

function stylize()
{
  index++;
  if (index > 7) index =1;
  var s = "myStyle" + index;
  var e = document.getElementById("MessageText");
  e.className = s;
  setTimeout("stylize()", 1500);
  return;
}
 </script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="stylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
     <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

MY CSS PAGE IS:.....

```
.myStyle1 {font-family:Impact; color:black; font-size:100}
.myStyle2 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:18}
.myStyl31 {font-family:Tahoma; color:black; font-size:24}
.myStyle4 {font-family:Verdana; color:black; font-size:48}
.myStyle5 {font-family:Impact; color:red; font-size:30}
.myStyle6 {font-family:Marlett; color:green; font-size:65}
.myStyle7 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:46}
.myStyle8 {font-family:Courier Sans MS Bold; color:blue; font-size:60}
.myStyle9 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle10 {font-family:Arial Italic; color:blue; font-size:10}
.myStyle11 {font-family:Times New Roman; color:blue; font-size:50}
.myStyle12 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:38}
.myStyle13 {font-family:Verdana; color:white; font-size:30}
.myStyle14 {font-family:Marlett; color:blue; font-size:70}
.myStyle15 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle16 {font-family:Georgia; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle17 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle18 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:12;}
.myStyle19 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:20;}
.myStyle20 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:55}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is working, all you need is the random function in there:

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Just do:

```
index = getRandomInt(1, 20);
```

Now you'll get a random number.